# Django TypeError at /servicesurvey/8:pk

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

This error occurs when I try to call another page to edit the information about the main service page.

TypeError at /servicesurvey/8:pk
edit_survey() got an unexpected keyword argument 'int'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8080/servicesurvey/8:pk
Django Version: 2.0
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:
edit_survey() got an unexpected keyword argument 'int'

home page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- /Css -->
    <link rel = "stylesheet"
    type = "text/css"
    href = "../static/survey.css" />
    <!-- /Css -->
    <title>Delta</title>

    <!-- /Fonts -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- /Fonts -->
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <div class="absolute">
                <h1 id="home_name">Delta</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="Delta" class="logoPrincipal">
                <img src="../static/logo.png" alt="Delta">
        </div>
        <div>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="{% url 'qrcode' %}">
                        <img src="../static/images.png" alt="Leia o QR Code com seu celular">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="{% url 'servicesurvey' %}">
                            <img src="../static/form.png" alt="Leia o QR Code com seu celular">
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul> 
        </div> 
        <div>
            <section>
                <p>teste123...</p>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div>
            <section>
                <p>teste123...</p>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

edit page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Editar Pesquisa</h1>
    <form class="formSurvey" action="{% url 'edit_survey' survey.id %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ surveyform }}
      <div class="row">
        <input type="submit" value="Editar">
      </div>
      </form>

</body>
</html>
```

url.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from survey import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('servicesurvey', views.servicesurvey, name='servicesurvey'),
    path('qrcode', views.qrcode, name='qrcode'),
    path('index', views.index, name='index'),
    path('servicesurvey/<int>:pk', views.edit_survey, name='edit_survey'),
]
```

the view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import SurveyForm
from .models import Survey

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'survey/home.html')


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'survey/index.html')


def servicesurvey(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        filled_form = SurveyForm(request.POST)
        if filled_form.is_valid():
            created_survey = filled_form.save()
            created_survey_pk = created_survey.id
            note = 'Obrigado por responder nossa pesquisa'
            new_form = SurveyForm()
            return render(request, 'survey/servicesurvey.html', {'created_survey_pk': created_survey_pk, 'surveyform': new_form, 'note':note})
    else:
        form = SurveyForm()
        return render(request, 'survey/servicesurvey.html', {'surveyform':form})

def qrcode(request):
    return render(request, 'survey/qrcode.html')

def edit_survey(request, pk):
    survey = Survey.objects.get(pk=pk)
    form = SurveyForm(instance=survey)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        filled_form = SurveyForm(request.POST, instance=survey)
        if filled_form.is_valid():
            filled_form.save()
            form = filled_form
    return render(request, 'survey/edit_survey.html', {'surveyform': form, 'survey': survey})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your this code line should be like

```
 path('servicesurvey/<int:pk>', views.edit_survey, name='edit_survey'),
```

instead of

```
 path('servicesurvey/<int>:pk', views.edit_survey, name='edit_survey'),
```

in urls.py

note the pk argument included with int